# Flatten data frame with array columns

Tags: python, pyspark

Suppose I have a PySpark dataframe whose `df.printSchema()` is:

```
root
 |-- shop_id: int (nullable = false)
 |-- items: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- item_id: int (nullable = false)
```

How can one convert it into this:

```
root
 |-- shop_id: int (nullable = false)
 |-- item_id: int (nullable = false)
```

In other words, within each entry `shop_id` is "attached" to every `item_id` and these pairs are directed into a single stream.

A more visual explanation:

before

```
[
   {
      "shop_id":42,
      "items":[{"item_id":101}, {"item_id":102}]
   },
   {
      "shop_id":43,
      "items":[{"item_id":203}]
   }
]
```

after

```
[
   {"shop_id":42,"item_id":101},
   {"shop_id":42,"item_id":102},
   {"shop_id":43,"item_id":203}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

```
df.select('shop_id',F.explode('items.item_id').alias('item_id'))
```

**test**

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, ArrayType, StructType, IntegerType

schema = StructType([
    StructField('shop_id', IntegerType()),
    StructField('items', ArrayType(
        StructType([
            StructField('item_id', IntegerType()),
        ])
    ))
])

data = [
   {
      "shop_id":42,
      "items":[{"item_id":101}, {"item_id":102}]
   },
   {
      "shop_id":43,
      "items":[{"item_id":203}]
   }
]

df = spark_session.createDataFrame(data, schema)
```

before

```
df.printSchema()

root
 |-- shop_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- items: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- item_id: integer (nullable = true)
```

after

```
df = df.select('shop_id',F.explode('items.item_id').alias('item_id'))
df.printSchema()

root
 |-- shop_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- item_id: integer (nullable = true)

df.collect()

[Row(shop_id=42, item_id=101),
 Row(shop_id=42, item_id=102),
 Row(shop_id=43, item_id=203)]
```